# Can i use facebook login for pc games using facebook unity sdk or playfab? if yes please guide me

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Can i use **facebook** login for **pc** games using **facebook** **unity** **sdk** or **playfab**?
If yes please guide me.
Playfab's documentation does not contain any code about it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use Facebook Unity SDK for PC games. Though, you can use it for WebGL games, but I believe this isn't what you are looking for.

From the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/):

> The Facebook SDK for Unity complements Unity Technologies' cross-platform support, providing a pure-Unity write-once, run-everywhere experience across the key gaming platforms of **WebGL, Unity Web Player, Android and iOS**.